# Did a try and catch test to find if user input is not a number. Need help to get that one JTextfield written in to get empty

Tags: java, try-catch, jtextfield

My try and catch method works and are able to find out if the text input at chosen JTextField is a number or not. ¨

when it's not a number the text should be removed and give a message that it's not a number, but so far I've only been able to remove the text written by using a for loop. Which removes all text on all JTextFields. I only need to remove the one that was just written by the user. I haven't been able to find the right way of putting what the for loop does in a way that only remove text a single time.

This is a Sudoku game, so it has like 81 text fields

You can find the test at the most outlined part with this comment above it:

//---------------------------------------------------------This test < Just want to remove that one felt user wrote in

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

/**
 * Created by Gaute on 1/30/2017.
 */

public class Assignment03GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    ArrayList<JTextField> txtfeltNummer = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");

    JMenu newGame = new JMenu("New Game");

    JMenuItem easy = new JMenuItem("Easy");
    JMenuItem medium = new JMenuItem("Medium");
    JMenuItem hard = new JMenuItem("Hard");

    JMenuItem deleteGame = new JMenuItem("Delete Game");

    public Assignment03GUI() {
        JFrame sudokuWindow = new JFrame();
        sudokuWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        sudokuWindow.setTitle("Sudoku");

        sudokuWindow.setLayout(new GridLayout(9, 0));
        sudokuWindow.setSize(1000,1000);

        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        fileMenu.add(newGame);
        fileMenu.add(deleteGame);

        newGame.add(easy);
        newGame.add(medium);
        newGame.add(hard);

        sudokuWindow.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JTextField tekstfelt;               //Deklarer variabelen så den kan brukes utenfor for løkka

        for (int i = 0; i < 81; i++) {
            tekstfelt = new JTextField();



            //---------------------------------------------------------This test < Just want to remove that one felt user wrote in
            tekstfelt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String text = ((JTextField) e.getSource()).getText();

                    try{
                        Integer.parseInt(text);
                        System.out.println("An integer");
                    }
                    catch (NumberFormatException e2) {
                        for (JTextField felt : txtfeltNummer) {
                            felt.setText("");
                            felt.setEditable(true);
                        }
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Ugyldig, ikke et tall");
                    }
                }
            });



            tekstfelt.setSize(100,100);

            tekstfelt.putClientProperty("id ", Integer.valueOf(i));

            txtfeltNummer.add(tekstfelt);
            sudokuWindow.add(tekstfelt);
        }

        easy.addActionListener(this);
        medium.addActionListener(this);
        hard.addActionListener(this);
        deleteGame.addActionListener(this);

        sudokuWindow.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Object source = e.getSource();

        if (source.equals(easy) || source.equals(medium) || source.equals(hard)) {
            for (JTextField felt : txtfeltNummer) {
                felt.setText(randomNumber(1, 9));
                felt.setEditable(true);

                int removeNumbers = Integer.parseInt(randomNumber(0, 3));

                if (source.equals(easy) && removeNumbers == 0) {
                    felt.setText("");
                }
                else if (source.equals(medium) && removeNumbers <= 1) {
                    felt.setText("");
                }
                else if (source.equals(hard) && removeNumbers <= 2) {
                    felt.setText("");
                }
                else {
                    felt.setEditable(false);
                }
            }
        }

        if (e.getSource().equals(deleteGame)) {
            System.out.println("Delete Game");

            for (JTextField felt : txtfeltNummer){
                felt.setText("");
                felt.setEditable(true);
            }
        }
    }

    public static String randomNumber(int min, int max) {
        int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);
        String randomNumString = Integer.toString(randomNum);

        return randomNumString;
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd probably be better off using a DocumentFilter: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html

Comment: That's something new to me

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer with some help from another site, all I had to do was to change

for (JTextField felt : txtfeltNummer)   **to**    JTextField felt = (JTextField) e.getSource();

```
tekstfelt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String text = ((JTextField) e.getSource()).getText();

                    try{
                        Integer.parseInt(text);
                        System.out.println("An integer");
                    }
                    catch (NumberFormatException e2) {
                        for (JTextField felt : txtfeltNummer) {
                            felt.setText("");
                            felt.setEditable(true);
                        }
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Ugyldig, ikke et tall");
                    }
                }
            });
```